# Does the number of elements in the queue affect resistance?

Tags: magicka

Is there any difference between (for example) `EF` self-cast and `EFFFF` self-cast? Is the resistance stronger or last longer or anything? Or should I just stick to the shortest sequence possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a test myself. The answer is yes. Queuing up `EFFFF` makes the shield last much longer than queuing up `EF`.